# Wrap content in two divs in a heading using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to turn this:

```
<div class="month_date">
    <div class="month_title">March, </div>
    <div class="month_title_year">  2016</div>
</div>
```

..into this using jQuery

```
<div class="month_date">
     <h3>March, 2016</h3>
</div>
```

Here's what I came up with but it's wrapping each the month and year headings individually.

```
jQuery('.month_date div').contents().unwrap().wrap("<h3></h3>");
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) at this context,

```
jQuery('.month_date div').contents().unwrap().unwrap().wrapAll("<h3></h3>");
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/seoxt30g/)

Answer (score 0):

No need for any wrapping or unwrapping:

```js
$('div.month_date').html(function(){
    return '<h3>'+$(this).find('div.month_title').text()+$(this).find('div.month_title_year').text()+'</h3>'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="month_date">
    <div class="month_title">March, </div>
    <div class="month_title_year"> 2016</div>
</div>
```